# How to load a view controller into a container view?

Tags: c#, ios, swift

I added a container view to the main controller view and am trying to load another controller view into that container from within the main controller `viewdidload` method like that (it's c# but near of swift I think):

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var view2= Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("View2");
        this.AddChildViewController(view2);
        view2.View.Frame = container.Frame;
        view2.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);
}
```

I get no error but nothing is shown anywhere.

So what am I missing?

Comment: if you added container view in storyboard then you can directly give other view controller as a child in storyboard only.

Comment: @Entretoize Please Use below code i have answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello You can use this code.

```
let view2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "View2")
addChildViewController(view2!)
view2?.view.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.viewContainer.frame.size.width, height: 
self.viewContainer.frame.size.height)
self.viewContainer.addSubview((view2?.view)!)
view2?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Comment: I missed the addSubview